# Gsm interfacing with atmega16

Tags: gsm, avr, at-command

I am working on GSM sim900D interfacing with Atmega16. Initially I made the circuit using MAX232 on breadboard. Then I connected it to my PC using a serial port. I tested AT commands, the commands worked perfectly on hyper terminal and I was able to send SMS using hyperterminal. Then I tested it on Proteus and it was working there perfectly too.

I am using codevision avr as the compiler. GSM work on 9600baud but the problem is that in compiler I have to keep the baud rate4800(clock = 1MHz) and at proteus COMPIM(physical baud=9600 & virtual baud=4800) only then it works when I run it on hardware(breadboard) it doesn't work as I have set the baud to 4800. I don't know how to set the baud for hardware. I tried 9600baud for hardware in compiler but it doesn't send SMS at all. Kindly tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

On ATmega16 (and other ATmegas), the serial baud rate is set via **UBRRH** and **UBRRL** registers plus the **U2X** bit in the **UCSRA** register.  The detailed description of how this works starts on page 146 of the [ATmega16 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2466.pdf).  Basically, UBRR is a 16-bit register and so must be accessed separately via 8 bit parts **UBRRH** (the high byte) and **UBRRL** (the low byte).  The value you want to put into these registers (and the **U2X** bit in **UCSRA** register) depends on

- the clock rate
- the desired baud rate.

For 1Mhz clock and 9600 baud there are two options (see table 68 on page 168 in the datasheet): cleared **U2X** bit and **UBRR** set to 6 or set **U2X** and **UBRR** set to 12. The latter option results in a baud rate generation that is closer to the desired baud rate (0.2%) error, therefore, the latter option is recommended. Consequently, the code you want is:

```
UBRRH = 0;
UBRRL = 12;
UCSRA |= 1<<(U2X);
```

There is a nasty gotcha lurking here: as the datasheet states, **UBRRH** and **UCSRC** are the same register. **UCSRC** controls parity, stop bits, and other important settings. Therefore if you ever need to write to **UCSRC**, make sure that you set the **URSEL** bit at the same time:

```
UCSRC = (1<<URSEL) | (...other bits...)
```

or

```
UCSRC |= (1<<URSEL) | (...other bits...)
```

Otherwise you will clobber your **UBRRH** register and wonder why your baud rate is not what you expected.

But you can also make use of the AVR Libc code, which provides a read-made way for setting a baud rate on AVR, see [util/setbaud.html](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__setbaud.html)

Answer (score 0):

you check data sheet the error rate is too high.  when you using 9600 baud rate on 1MHZ this is the main problem . take 8,12,16 MHZ as possible and check data sheet . and dont forget to burn fuse bits related to XTAL frequency if you not burn these bits properly that relate with crystal  that is not work properly .

if u need more help ask..